# Angular 6 Animation not displaying

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

Im trying to add animation spinner to my angular app

i find this spinner:

https://codepen.io/z-/pen/OPzNLz

spinner.component.html

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css'],
  animations: []
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```css
/*Negative delay values skip rather than pause.*/

.test {
  background: yellow;
}

.row1 .left,
.row1 .right {
  animation-delay: -0s;
  /*Obviously not needed*/
}

.row2 .left,
.row2 .right {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.row3 .left,
.row3 .right {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}

.row4 .left,
.row4 .right {
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
}


/**/

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 84px;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 6px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  left: 0px;
  animation: left 2s infinite;
}

.right {
  right: 0px;
  animation: right 2s infinite;
}

.row1,
.row2,
.row3,
.row4 {
  position: relative;
}

.row1 {
  top: 0px;
}

.row2 {
  top: 26px;
}

.row3 {
  top: 52px;
}

.row4 {
  top: 78px;
}

@keyframes left {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 90px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 170px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 10px;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 90px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 10px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Spinner</div>

<div class="loader">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I took the HTML & CSS file, and copy it to a plain html and css and the spinner showed up.

then i thought why not use it as a component in angular

so i copy the code into a component, but the spinner not seems to work
it just dont show up - with no error.

I even check  BrowserAnimationsModule  is imported in app.module.ts 
but its dosent seems to change.

Comment: Because Im using this in a several location in my app, while getting data from backend

Comment: How can i use this in angular? let's say i have this in an external file how can i show the html in a component?

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was the Notes e.g /**/ in the css.

Comment: So the problem was that the styles at `.css` were commented?
xD